# Reading variable from another file into bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, expect

I have written a bash script which calls other process (the ones that ask for password on terminal).

```
#!/bin/bash
source pc.txt
snp_pw=$export_snapshot
export snapshot_pw=snp_pw
echo_time() {
    date "+%d:%b:%Y:%H:%M:%S"
}
# Export Snapshot
echo "$(echo_time) :STARTING EXPORT SNAPPSHOT SCRIPT" | tee -a ${mail_log}
loop_var=3
echo "$(echo_time) :ON FAILURE TRY AT MAX ${loop_var} ATTEMPTS" | tee -a ${mail_log}
i=1
while [ "${loop_var}" -gt 0 ]; do
expect <(cat << 'EOD'
spawn $::env(Snp_Script_Path)/export_service_instance.sh bootstrap Export_Files/test.bar
expect "Enter RPD Password:"
send -- "$::env(snapshot_pw)\r"
expect "Re-enter RPD Password:"
send -- "$::env(snapshot_pw)\r"
interact
EOD
) &> ${export_snapshot_log_location}
```

Instead of directly hardcoding the password here, how can I read it from within a variable in other file?

It has to be a bash and expect both.
I am currently trying to read the file through source and $pass gives password. But within expect, it is not working.

I don't want to encrypt/encode anything. I just want to keep it simple.

Comment: Please show what you have tried. I can imagine a few errors that you could have made. But as I can not see what you did, I do not know.

Comment: First I am reading a text file(It has got pwd=value in it) using source
source passcode.txt
pass=$pwd
and then within expect this pass variable I am unable to read

Comment: show me the code, (edit question).

Comment: I have edited and added some snippet

Comment: And which part of the code you added is the minimum to show your problem?

Comment: send -- "$::env(snapshot_pw)\r"   -> This ideally reads bash variables. But in this case it is not reading.. This is what i want to reslove

Comment: take a look at [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) with which you can write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of everything that's happening,
and what is supposed to be happening,
but when you say

```
export snapshot_pw=snp_pw
```

you are setting the environment variable `snapshot_pw`
to the string `s` `n` `p` `_` `p` `w`. 
You probably want to do

```
export snapshot_pw="$snp_pw"
```

to set the environment variable `snapshot_pw`
to the *value* of variable `snp_pw`, i.e., `$snp_pw`.

Also, you should quote the shell variable `"$mail_log"`
and any others you use without quoting. 
(You don't need the `{` and `}`.)

Answer (score 0):

A minimal test case shows that both `bash` and `expect` do read the same environment variable:

```
#!/bin/bash
export foo="bar$$"
echo "bash $foo"

expect <(cat <<'EOD'
puts "tcl  $env(foo)"
EOD
)
```

which when run shows the same values in both languages:

```
-bash-4.2$ bash mixin
bash bar7242
tcl  bar7242
-bash-4.2$ bash mixin
bash bar7247
tcl  bar7247
-bash-4.2$
```

so it is not clear what you mean by "it is not reading" nor what your overall goal is for this code.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable based on the contents of a file with a syntax like

```
snp_pw="$(cat passwd_file)"
```

e.g.

```
$ cat passwd_file 
anewpassword

$ cat x
#!/bin/bash

snp_pw=$(cat passwd_file)

echo Password is $snp_pw

$ ./x
Password is anewpassword
```

Comment: With bash, you can avoid `cat` using: `snp_pw=$(<passwd_file)` -- ref https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution

Comment: Also, if you do this, you'll want to make the password file hidden and unreadable by others: `mv passwd_file .passwd_file; chmod 600 .passwd_file`